# Android - Mapsforge drag and drop marker

Tags: maps, drag, marker

Im am using mapsforge in my Android app. I am looking for a way to make the marker dragable. The user should be able to mark a specific point on the map by moving the marker. I tried the mapsforge group as well but didn´t find an answer. Has anyone succeeded in implenting drag and drop? Thank you for your help.